# Taking the text inside each <p> which is a child node of div and storing inside a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read the content inside paragraph tag which is the child node of div and storing those values into and passing the array to the controller
here is the code:

```
 <div class = "proposal">
    <p> one </p>
    <p> two </p> 
    <p> three </p>
    <p> three </p> 
    <p> three </p>
    <p> three </p>
    </div> 
    Please help me to get the content of paragraph and store into an array using jquery.
I am trying to get a solution in this way:

var proposal = $("#Proposal").contents().filter(function() {
                                return this.nodeType === 3;
                            }) .wrap( "<p></p>" ).end();
```

I am getting the object but,

```
for(i=0;i<proposal.length;i++){
    proposal = proposal[i].innerHTML
}
```

giving me the error that,
 **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = $(".proposal p").map(function() {

  return $(this).text()

}).get();


console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="proposal">
  <p> one </p>
  <p> two </p>
  <p> three </p>
  <p> three </p>
  <p> three </p>
  <p> three </p>
</div>
```

1. Use `.map()` to add into array.
2. Use `.text()` with selector `$(".proposal p")` -> meaning all child p of element with class proposal

Answer (score 1):

This will get each p and push it into the array.

```
var data = [];

$(".proposal p").each(function () {
    data.push($(this).text());
});
```